# Accelerometer events stacking up when iOS app is suspended. Is this data accurate?

Tags: ios, logging, accelerometer, core-motion, suspend

My app gets accelerometer data updates (currently running on 1sec interval).
If the app becomes suspended (turn off the display for example), the handler of the updates is no longer triggered (as expected).

When the app is again active, the handler is instantly called with a value for every missed second.

My questions are:
1. Is this data accurate? (Opposed to be somehow interpolated from previous values)
2. How long will the data be stacked up like this, i.e. what is the max interval for which I will have logged data? (will it call my handler 3600 times to make up for the 3600 values it has logged for the passed hour of turned-off display/suspension?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the logged data seems to be accurate, my test showed that it stopped logging after about 220-240 seconds (which in my case is 240 updates of the accelerometer data).

I have tested it on iPad with iOS 6.1.